# Correlation of Three Discrete Signals

Tags: similarities, cross-correlation

I want to perform a test to determine the similarity between three discrete signals. The waveforms represent one test subject performing the same action under the same conditions for three trials, so it is expected that they will be somewhat similar. My original thought was to perform a cross-correlation of the signals, but I only know how to do that with two signals. Is there a way to measure the similarity between all three signals?

My other thought was to take a cross-correlation of signals 1 and 2, and 2 and 3. Then I am not sure whether I could take a cross-correlation or maybe an average of those two results.